# Split Text Documents Into Pages (in Vim?)

Tags: vim, rfc

I am wondering if there exists a way to split text documents into pages in a format similar to RFC documents. [Here](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) is an example of an RFC document that splits pages at what appears to be 56 lines.

I've already been able to get lines to break at word boundaries at a certain line width using `set formatoptions+=w` and `set textwidth=72`.

That being said, if there does not exist a Vim solution, are there any programs or command line utilities that could offer similar functionality?

Comment: You could accomplish this with a fairly complex macro. At the start, write your initial header and footer, then in the macro you can keep yanking/pasting the previous header and footer whilst incrementing the page number (`C-a`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a tool called ***[pr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pr)*** that's used for formatting files before they're printed, with some fiddling with configuration you may be able to get the desired result.

Edit: After a bit of fiddling I came up with this command which split a readme of mine up into four pages of 20 lines. You could probably then do a find and replace to get the desired header format.

```
pr -F -l 20 README.md
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a custom command. Here's a sketch:

```
command! -count=56 Paginate
\   let page = 1 |
\   <count> |
\   while line('.') < line('$') |
\       call append('.', ['-------', 'page ' . page, '=======']) |
\       let page += 1 |
\       .+<count>+3 |
\   endwhile
```